# Question about job interview - Penetration Tester

Tags: penetration-test

I am little scared about following question:

why do you want to be a penetration tester?

Can anyone help me with an example of ethical answer?

Comment: Welcome to Security.SE. I think this question might be classed as "primarily opinion-based" and closed as it is not a good fit for this site. Maybe you could discuss this in chat instead?

Comment: it is primary based opinion. Every one wants to be something because of this or that reason

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is that you should answer honestly :) (it likely won't end well if you start making stuff up in interviews..)

That said there are many reasons why someone might want to be an Pen. tester, some options would be

- Interested in technology and really want to get to understand the way things work.
- Interested in understanding security, how it works, and how it fails.
- Want a good hands-on technical role that's regularly challenging.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is usually along the lines of...

I started it for the same reason I suspect most people do, as a teenager, because I thought it was cool. Once I then got into it properly, I found that it was deeply rewarding due to the level of challenge involved, and the feeling that you were pitting your ability and intellect against that of the security team on the other side. There aren't many other roles that can give you that same feeling of success as when you type "id" and get "root" as the response.